# Delete rows from Table X if fields in Table Y hold the same data

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to delete rows in Table X if they have duplicates in Table Y but *only* if one of the fields in Table Y hold a certain value (`statuscode`)? I'm working with data created by a 3rd-party software and one of my requirements is to remove duplicate data should they exist.

I've been trying to figure this out but I admit I need help.

```
DELETE tableX FROM tableX
    INNER JOIN tableY
    ON tableX.apples = tableY.apples AND
    tableX.oranges = tableY.oranges AND
    WHERE tableY.statuscode = 200
```

I'm trying to search and delete without the use of a date but I'm  still unable to delete anything. Is there a right way of doing this?

Comment: Replace `DELETE tableX` with `SELECT tableX.*` and see if any results are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE x FROM x
INNER JOIN y
ON x.c1 = y.c1 AND
x.c2 = y.c2 
WHERE y.statuscode = 200
```

Working Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7465/1

Comment: How is this different from OPs approach?

Comment: @hjpotter92 OP said "I am unable to delete anything". This query deletes duplicates as visible in the fiddle. OP's query has a syntax error which I am not sure if it was a typing mistake or not.